# AWS Amplify withAuthenticator HoC - social media login?

Tags: react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify Authentication on my React Native app using the `withAuthentication` HoC. I would like to implement federated signin with Google and Facebook which has already been configured on these platforms. Unfortunately I have no idea how I implement social media buttons on the AWS UI component; AWS documentation suggests that configuration is passed to the HoC, but no further information is provided...

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {
                // display federation/social provider buttons 
                federated: {myFederatedConfig}, 
})
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also not able to find how can I add social provider like Google, Apple sign in `withAuthenticator` HOC?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up not using this HOC in favour of making calls to `Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'provider })`